# Is truth telling important or just having good intentions is enough?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, truth

Are good intentions enough to warrant not telling the truth?

I am especially interested in when we've already lied, and the point in question is whether we should **confess**.

Do any philosophers write about these sorts of questions?

Comment: It depends on the context: in a courthouse, "good intentions" can be not enough. On the specific topic you are alluding to... there is a long tradition about "do not tell all the truth".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in courthouse it won't matter, i am not cheating, just my own demons. I haven't told certain things. I never tell my secrets to anyone, my insecurities that is the part i am talking about.

Comment: you could read truth and truthfulness by williams, it is or includes an interesting little course on questions like that, and faairly accessible. fwiw i feel that people that are able to tell the truth are better off, tho i suppose life isn't so perfect

Comment: What does "the road to hell is paved with good intentions" mean to you?

Comment: I will say...not always and so is the road to heaven ;)
and if we just say the truth how different are we from a program

Answer (score 2):

(I am going to pretend as far as possible that this is a philosophy question, while at the same time voting to close because it isn't.  This is what I generally do for such things.)

I disagree with Kant's conclusion on lying.  It focusses on meaning as the essence of language, and assumes the basic maxim for lying is to say one thing and mean another.

But often, we say something false, but convey a deeper meaning which is true.  For stories, the suspension of truth is explicit, so it is not really deceptive.  But there are other occasions.

For me, the test case here is promises.  Every promise is a lie, no one can predict the future or assure a given outcome.  But the intention matters more.  And we do not delineate promises from calculated predictions in which we attest faith.  So we are not suspending truth, as in a story.  We are speaking a truth through the medium of falsehood.

In the same sense, one's own mythology is not a set of stories, nor does it lie.  It tells a truth via false statements.

So is there a truly general maxim that still handles this case?

Well, note that promises meant simply to manipulate, are not acceptable, they are disrespectful.  So I would propose that respect, and not the underlying factual truth of the proposition is the essential problem with lying.

I think you can universalize "Speak what truth most deeply respects your listener" as an ideal goal over "Speak the factual truth in all cases".

So was your motivation when you lied disrespectful?  Does that motive remain, or has it been obviated?  Is it a change of sentiment that it is more respectful to confess, or not to confess?