# Is it a good argument in utilitarianism that you should always be truthful because you might later change your values?

Tags: ethics, utilitarianism

I was thinking that one might justify lying because using his values he can maximize the utility of all people in the future by doing so. But then this came to my mind that what if someone changes his values? What if he realizes his values were wrong? Could we here say that being truthful is indifferent to values and is always the right thing to do? or is it not a good argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it is virtually impossible to argue that being truthful is indifferent to values.  If you choose to tell the truth in a situation where definite harm will result from your truthfulness, then preventing that harm is either a value, or it is not.

Choosing correctness over responsibility to protect others is a value judgement in-and-of-itself, and cannot be values-neutral.  Sissela Bok makes a thorough and convincing (if a bit boring) analysis of the balance point in [http://www.amazon.com/Lying-Moral-Choice-Public-Private/dp/0375705287](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375705287).  But it is obvious that the methodology of balance already requires a value system.

I am a gay man who has worked professionally with people with Borderline Personality Disorder.  Consider two scenarios directly related to my real life:

'Outing' people who are married because one feels that telling the truth has value in-and-of-itself can be harmful to their children.  Waiting until it is safe to do so generally requires lying now and apologizing later.

Some 'borderline' people purposely do damage through the emotions of others, by choosing the right time to make them angry or to scare them into behavior that is unwise.  They commonly arrange to use truth as a tool.  (One way they do so is exposing truths to authority in a way and at a time that will cause harm, say precipitating depression and a return to drug use, or deepening isolation of a fragile family member who will consequently not get help when they need it.)  The easiest way to circumvent such tactics is to make it obvious up front that you know when to lie.

It is hard to imagine making the estimates of damage involved in ways that would not change as my values shifted.  Utility remains subjective and our deliberations are always incomplete.  (Thankfully, the moment is the moment, and self-forgiveness does not depend upon being right.)

I have argued elsewhere ([Is truth telling important or just having good intentions is enough?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/34736/is-truth-telling-important-or-just-having-good-intentions-is-enough/34738#34738)) that truth is not the right standard for ethical judgment, but instead, respect for individuals is.  But what action expresses respect does change with your values.  Respect motivates protection if you value safety highly, and may motivate withdrawal of that same protection if you value autonomy and independence more highly.